# Substring in Data Frame R

Tags: json, r, gps, substring

I have data from GPS log like this : (this data in rows of data frame columns)

```
{"mAccuracy":20.0,"mAltitude":0.0,"mBearing":0.0,"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":21677339000000,"mExtras":{"networkLocationSource":"cached","networkLocationType":"wifi","noGPSLocation":{"mAccuracy":20.0,"mAltitude":0.0,"mBearing":0.0,"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":21677339000000,"mHasAccuracy":true,"mHasAltitude":false,"mHasBearing":false,"mHasSpeed":false,"mIsFromMockProvider":false,"mLatitude":35.1811956,"mLongitude":126.9104909,"mProvider":"network","mSpeed":0.0,"mTime":1402801381486},"travelState":"stationary"},"mHasAccuracy":true,"mHasAltitude":false,"mHasBearing":false,"mHasSpeed":false,"mIsFromMockProvider":false,"mLatitude":35.1811956,"mLongitude":126.9104909,"mProvider":"network","mSpeed":0.0,"mTime":1402801381486,"timestamp":1402801665.512}
```

The problem is I only need Latitude and longitude value, so I think i can use substring and sappy for applying to all data in dataframe.

But I am not sure this way is handsome because when i use substring ex: `substr("abcdef", 2, 4)` so I need to count who many chars from beginning until "mLatitude" , so anybody can give suggestion the fast way to processing it?

Thank you to @mnel for answering question, it's work , but i still have problem

From mnel answer I've created function like this :

```
fgps <- function(x) {
     out <- fromJSON(x)
     c(out$mExtras$noGPSLocation$mLatitude,
       out$mExtras$noGPSLocation$mLongitude)
}
```

and then this is my data :

```
gpsdata <- head(dfallgps[,4],2)

[1] "{\"mAccuracy\":23.128,\"mAltitude\":0.0,\"mBearing\":0.0,\"mElapsedRealtimeNanos\":76437488000000,\"mExtras\":{\"networkLocationSource\":\"cached\",\"networkLocationType\":\"wifi\",\"noGPSLocation\":{\"mAccuracy\":23.128,\"mAltitude\":0.0,\"mBearing\":0.0,\"mElapsedRealtimeNanos\":76437488000000,\"mHasAccuracy\":true,\"mHasAltitude\":false,\"mHasBearing\":false,\"mHasSpeed\":false,\"mIsFromMockProvider\":false,\"mLatitude\":35.1779956,\"mLongitude\":126.9089661,\"mProvider\":\"network\",\"mSpeed\":0.0,\"mTime\":1402894224187},\"travelState\":\"stationary\"},\"mHasAccuracy\":true,\"mHasAltitude\":false,\"mHasBearing\":false,\"mHasSpeed\":false,\"mIsFromMockProvider\":false,\"mLatitude\":35.1779956,\"mLongitude\":126.9089661,\"mProvider\":\"network\",\"mSpeed\":0.0,\"mTime\":1402894224187,\"timestamp\":1402894517.425}"
[2] "{\"mAccuracy\":1625.0,\"mAltitude\":0.0,\"mBearing\":0.0,\"mElapsedRealtimeNanos\":77069916000000,\"mExtras\":{\"networkLocationSource\":\"cached\",\"networkLocationType\":\"cell\",\"noGPSLocation\":{\"mAccuracy\":1625.0,\"mAltitude\":0.0,\"mBearing\":0.0,\"mElapsedRealtimeNanos\":77069916000000,\"mHasAccuracy\":true,\"mHasAltitude\":false,\"mHasBearing\":false,\"mHasSpeed\":false,\"mIsFromMockProvider\":false,\"mLatitude\":35.1811881,\"mLongitude\":126.9084072,\"mProvider\":\"network\",\"mSpeed\":0.0,\"mTime\":1402894857416},\"travelState\":\"stationary\"},\"mHasAccuracy\":true,\"mHasAltitude\":false,\"mHasBearing\":false,\"mHasSpeed\":false,\"mIsFromMockProvider\":false,\"mLatitude\":35.1811881,\"mLongitude\":126.9084072,\"mProvider\":\"network\",\"mSpeed\":0.0,\"mTime\":1402894857416,\"timestamp\":1402894857.519}"
```

When run sapply why the data still shows in the result not just the results values.

```
sapply(gpsdata, function(gpsdata) fgps(gpsdata))




    {"mAccuracy":23.128,"mAltitude":0.0,"mBearing":0.0,"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":76437488000000,"mExtras":{"networkLocationSource":"cached","networkLocationType":"wifi","noGPSLocation":{"mAccuracy":23.128,"mAltitude":0.0,"mBearing":0.0,"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":76437488000000,"mHasAccuracy":true,"mHasAltitude":false,"mHasBearing":false,"mHasSpeed":false,"mIsFromMockProvider":false,"mLatitude":35.1779956,"mLongitude":126.9089661,"mProvider":"network","mSpeed":0.0,"mTime":1402894224187},"travelState":"stationary"},"mHasAccuracy":true,"mHasAltitude":false,"mHasBearing":false,"mHasSpeed":false,"mIsFromMockProvider":false,"mLatitude":35.1779956,"mLongitude":126.9089661,"mProvider":"network","mSpeed":0.0,"mTime":1402894224187,"timestamp":1402894517.425}
[1,]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        35.178
[2,]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       126.909
     {"mAccuracy":1625.0,"mAltitude":0.0,"mBearing":0.0,"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":77069916000000,"mExtras":{"networkLocationSource":"cached","networkLocationType":"cell","noGPSLocation":{"mAccuracy":1625.0,"mAltitude":0.0,"mBearing":0.0,"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":77069916000000,"mHasAccuracy":true,"mHasAltitude":false,"mHasBearing":false,"mHasSpeed":false,"mIsFromMockProvider":false,"mLatitude":35.1811881,"mLongitude":126.9084072,"mProvider":"network","mSpeed":0.0,"mTime":1402894857416},"travelState":"stationary"},"mHasAccuracy":true,"mHasAltitude":false,"mHasBearing":false,"mHasSpeed":false,"mIsFromMockProvider":false,"mLatitude":35.1811881,"mLongitude":126.9084072,"mProvider":"network","mSpeed":0.0,"mTime":1402894857416,"timestamp":1402894857.519}
[1,]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      35.18119
[2,]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     126.90841
```

I want the result looks like :

```
    [1] 35.178   126.909     
[2] 35.18119 126.90841
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that your data is  in `JSON` format. Therefore, use a `RJSONIO::fromJSON` to read the file.

E.g.:

```
txt <- "{\"mAccuracy\":20.0,\"mAltitude\":0.0,\"mBearing\":0.0,\"mElapsedRealtimeNanos\":21677339000000,\"mExtras\":{\"networkLocationSource\":\"cached\",\"networkLocationType\":\"wifi\",\"noGPSLocation\":{\"mAccuracy\":20.0,\"mAltitude\":0.0,\"mBearing\":0.0,\"mElapsedRealtimeNanos\":21677339000000,\"mHasAccuracy\":true,\"mHasAltitude\":false,\"mHasBearing\":false,\"mHasSpeed\":false,\"mIsFromMockProvider\":false,\"mLatitude\":35.1811956,\"mLongitude\":126.9104909,\"mProvider\":\"network\",\"mSpeed\":0.0,\"mTime\":1402801381486},\"travelState\":\"stationary\"},\"mHasAccuracy\":true,\"mHasAltitude\":false,\"mHasBearing\":false,\"mHasSpeed\":false,\"mIsFromMockProvider\":false,\"mLatitude\":35.1811956,\"mLongitude\":126.9104909,\"mProvider\":\"network\",\"mSpeed\":0.0,\"mTime\":1402801381486,\"timestamp\":1402801665.512}"
```

Then process:

```
library(RJSONIO)
out <- fromJSON(txt)
out$$mLongitude
#[1] 126.9105
out$mLatitude
#[1] 35.1812

# to process multiple values

tt <- rep(txt,2)

myData <- lapply(tt, fromJSON)
latlong <- do.call(rbind,lapply(myData, `[` ,c('mLatitude','mLongitude')))   
# or using rbind list

library(data.table)
latlong <- rbindlist(lapply(myData, `[` ,c('mLatitude','mLongitude')))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer,its work and i still have problem when run sapply in my dataframe, i already edited my question, i hope you can help me again, thank you